# What is the difference between list and list[:] in python?

Tags: python

What, if any, is the difference between `list` and `list[:]` in python?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

When reading, `list` is a reference to the original list, and `list[:]` shallow-copies the list.

When assigning, `list` (re)binds the name and `list[:]` slice-assigns, replacing what was previously in the list.

Also, don't use `list` as a name since it shadows the built-in.

Comment: Which is faster when assigning? list or list[:]

Answer (score 32):

The latter is a reference to a copy of the list and not a reference to the list. So it's very useful.

```
>>> li = [1,2,3]
>>> li2 = li
>>> li3 = li[:]
>>> li2[0] = 0
>>> li
[0, 2, 3]
>>> li3
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: But this does not work for np. array...

Answer (score 6):

li[:] creates a copy of the original list. But it does not refer to the same list object. Hence you don't risk changing the original list by changing the copy created by li[:].

for example:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = list1
>>> list3 = list1[:]
>>> list1[0] = 4
>>> list2
[4, 2, 3]
>>> list3
[1, 2, 3]
```

Here `list2` is changed by changing `list1` but `list3` doesn't change.

Answer (score 5):

Another useful example is when assigning a different type to a list and list[:]. for example,

```
l = [1,2,3]
a = numpy.array([4,5,6])
l = a
print(l)
```

The result is a numpy array:

```
array([4, 5, 6])
```

while,

```
l = [1,2,3]
a = numpy.array([4,5,6])
l[:] = a
print(l)
```

the result is a list:

```
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

To apply the first `list` to a variable will create a reference to the original list.
The second `list[i]` will create a shallow copy.

for example:

```
foo = [1,2,3]
bar = foo
foo[0] = 4
```

bar and foo will now be:

```
[4,2,3]
```

but:

```
foo = [1,2,3]
bar = foo[:]
foo[0] = 4
```

result will be:

```
bar == [1,2,3]
foo == [4,2,3]
```

`:` is to slice.

Answer (score 4):

However, if the list elements are lists themselves, even `list1 = list[:]` has its problems. Consider:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b[0].remove(2)
>>> b 
[[1, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> a
[[1, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

This happens because each list element being copied to b is a list itself, and this copying of lists involves the same problem that occurs with the normal `list1 = list2`.
The shortest way out **that I've found** is to explicitly copy every list element this way:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> b=[[j for j in i] for i in a]   
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> b[0].remove(2)
>>> b
[[1, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Of course, for every additional degree of nesting in the nested list, the copying code deepens by an additional inline `for` loop.

Comment: This will run into serious problems if you have different or unknown levels of nesting in your outer list (`i` may not be iterable) If you have nested lists, you should be using the [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module, use `b = copy.deepcopy(a)` instead of nested for loops.

Answer (score 3):

**The first one references to the original list. The second one points to the copy of the original list.**
Check this out!

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> c = a[:]
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
True
>>> a == c
True
>>> a is c
False
>>> a.__repr__
<method-wrapper '__repr__' of list object at 0x7f87a9ba3688>
>>> a.__repr__()
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>> b.__repr__
<method-wrapper '__repr__' of list object at 0x7f87a9ba3688>
>>> c.__repr__
<method-wrapper '__repr__' of list object at 0x7f87ad352988>
```

Notice that both **a** and **b** point to the address **0x7f87a9ba3688** whereas, **c** points to **0x7f87ad352988**.
The difference is crystal clear.
Both **a** and **b** reference to the original list object.
Whereas, **c** points to the copy (of the original list) and thus, it is in a different location.