# python list conversion

Tags: python, list

hi
how to convert a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
into a = [1, 2, 3, 4]  in one line in python ?

Comment: Categorical downvote to questions using the phrase "in one line"...

Comment: not that it is unreasonabe, but why is "in one line" a requirement?

Answer (score 8):

With a list comprehension.

```
a[:] = [int(x) for x in a]
```

Comment: >>> a = [int(x) for x in a[:]] (I would do it like this, In words: make a list of int(x) for every x in a copy of a, make it the new a). I'm unable to see such an explanation to your way. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: @ThisIsMeMoony: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081561/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-list-in-python/4081587#4081587

Comment: @ThisIsMeMoony: In addition to what Ignacio posted, your code is needlessly making a shallow copy (you can just iterate the old list without slicing).

Answer (score 8):

You can use `map()`:

```
a = map(int, a)
```

This is an alternative to the (more common) list comprehension, that can be more succinct in some cases.

Comment: If you are working in Python 3, you have just replaced a list with an iterator - these are not always interchangeable.

Comment: That's true. In Python 3, to make sure you have a list, use `a = list(map(int, a))`.

Answer (score 1):

With a **generator**:

```
a[:] = (int(x) for x in a)
```

... list comprehensions are so ummmmm, 2.1, don't you know?

but please be wary of replacing the contents in situ; compare this:

```
>>> a = b = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> a[:] = [int(x) for x in a]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

with this:

```
>>> a = b = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> a = [int(x) for x in a]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit presumptuous to assume that a generator can be used instead of a list in the original case?

Comment: It works with a generator, but it's pointless because the implementation creates a temporary list internally, and if it didn't, the code would blow up because the list would be modified while reading it. Using a list instead of a generator would force people trying to understand your code to think how `a[:] = ...` works internally to be sure that it won't blow up.

Comment: @pafcu - note the assignment is not to `a` but to `a[:]`, which will replace the contents of list `a` with the values returned by the generator.

Comment: @Rosh Oxy: It was intended to be an ironical supplement to the pointless `[:]` in the `a[:] = [int(x) for x in a]` answer which is sillier than `a = [....]` which is not as terse as `a = map(int, a)`. I crave your pardon for causing you to think.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = []
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
l = [(int(x)) for x in a]
print l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: While this code may be correct, please provide some explanation.