# Subtract a value from every number in a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
 a = [49, 51, 53, 56]
```

How do I subtract 13 from each integer value in the list?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

With a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = [x - 13 for x in a]
```

Comment: Thanks, Good work. :)

How do you put that into a function quickly?

Comment: By putting `def minus13(a):` on the line above and indenting one level.

Comment: Why `a[:]` on the lhs instead of just assigning back to `a`?  Doesn't `a[:]` create a copy of the list?

Comment: istruble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081561/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-list-in-python

Comment: What *should* be done is that the value from the list comprehension should be returned by the function, and the caller should decide to replace the existing sequence if appropriate.

Comment: IVA: Thanks.  That is what I was guessing but I was not finding much on docs.python.org with my initial searches.  It just seemed like possible early optimizing ;)  Josh:  I was writing the same answer but with just `a` on the lhs.

Comment: `minus13()` is a function you define in your code, which returns the result of the list comprehension. The rest is the creation of the list and the invocation of the function which occurs elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @istruble: Just assigning directly to a will work just as well. So `a = [x - 13 for x in a]` will work just as  well, and is less confusing.

Comment: @Lennart: Unless other references to the list exist, and you want them to contain the modified values.

Comment: @Ignacio: True, but that was not in the question, and and in my experience it's not a very common usecase. Maybe it depends on your style, but I never to that.

Answer (score 81):

If are you working with numbers a lot, you might want to take a look at [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). It lets you perform all kinds of operation directly on numerical arrays. For example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> array = numpy.array([49, 51, 53, 56])
>>> array - 13
array([36, 38, 40, 43])
```

Comment: I did a quick test and it returns a new array leaving the original array untouched.

Comment: @francois if you want it to save you have to do array = array-13

Answer (score 12):

You can use [map()](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map) function:

```
a = list(map(lambda x: x - 13, a))
```

Comment: @Frost.baka In Python 3, map returns map object. In Python 2, it returns list.

Answer (score 9):

To clarify an already posted solution due to questions in the comments

```
import numpy

array = numpy.array([49, 51, 53, 56])
array = array - 13
```

will output:

> array([36, 38, 40, 43])

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  a[i] -= 13
```

Comment: The list comprehension solution is much more pythonic.  You might like them.  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Who deleted my comment? - I don't see the point in counting the length of a. To make a simple calculation.

Comment: The count is necessary, if the algorithm is to be expressed this way, for an index variable (`i`) to iterate through all possible index values. This index variable is needed to mutate each element in the list.

Comment: Using range and len together in python is almost always a code smell, invariably there's a better way of doing things as in the numerous examples given above.