# if loops and Arrays

Tags: arrays, loops, numpy, if-statement

Im trying to plot some data from an experiment but the timer starts a bit before the start of my variable. I have tried to create a new list of times starting from 0 but when I do so my loop generates more values for my array then the length of the original array which makes it impossible to plot.

```
Aplate = np.loadtxt('Plates Angular poston_2.txt')

t1 = []
for i in Aplate:
    t = Aplate[:,0]
      for j in t:
      if j < 27.4150:
         x = j -3.01 
         t1.append(x)
     else:
         break 

y = Aplate[:,1]

plt.plot(t1, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could you edit your question and addin an example of what the current output is and an example of the output you are trying to work towards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply accounting for a constant delay in the start of data recording, why not just do

```
plt.plot( t-delay ,y )
```

where delay is 3.01? ( see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4918586/4916534 )

Also, if you want the columns to be the same length, why not populate y and t in the same loop? You are currently asking python to give you x values for all times < 27.4150, but to give you y values for all times.