# Difference between a[:] = b and a = b[:]? (Python)

Tags: python, sequence, slice

I was asked this for a coding test and didn't know the answer. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between list and list\[:\] in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081561/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-list-in-python)

Comment: @Ignacio: No, this is not a duplicate -- that question makes no mention of the `a[:] = b` construct.

Comment: @Adam: Not even the part that starts "When assigning..."?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[:]` is the slice operator.

When it's on the left side, it overwrites the contents of the list without creating a new reference.

When it's on the right side, it creates a copy of the list with the same contents.

Comment: Ohhh ok it makes sense now. To clarify, id(a) doesn't change when doing a[:] = b. id(a) changes when doing a = b[:]. Is there a reason why one may be better than the other?

Comment: Yes, you've got it exactly.  If `c` also refers to the same list as `a`, then you might want to change the contents, so that both variables refer to the updated list.

Answer (score 3):

`a = b[:]` calls either [`__getslice__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) or [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) on `b` and assigns the result to `a`.  In nearly all cases (e.g. lists, tuples, and other sequence types), this makes a shallow copy of the sequence; I don't know of any classes that don't implement that behavior, but you could have a user-defined type that did something different.  Any other objects that previously referred to the old value of `a` will continue to refer to that old value.

`a[:] = b`, on the other hand, calls [`__setslice__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setslice__) or [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) to replace a subset of the elements of `a` with those of the sequence `b`.  In this case, if the sequence type of `a` is well-behaved, this will replace the entirety of `a`, since the range `:` without endpoints indicates the entire sequence.  The difference here is that immutable types, such as tuples, will not allow you to perform `__setslice__` (e.g. by throwing a `TypeError` exception).  Any other objects that previously referred to `a` will also be updated, since the underlying object is being modified.

For mutable types such as `list`, the result of `a = b[:]` will be identical to `a[:] = b`, in that `a` will be a shallow copy of `b`; for immutable types such as `tuple`, `a[:] = b` is invalid.  For badly-behaved user-defined types, all bets are off.  There's also a difference in what happens to other objects that referred to the same object as `a` -- with `a = b[:]`, they refer to the original value (`a`), but with `a[:] = b`, they refer to the modified object (shallow copy of `b`).

Answer (score 2):

In both cases you end up the list `a` being a copy of the list `b`. But the method used to accomplish this has changed.

`a[:] = b` modifies the list `a` so that it has the same elements as `b`

`a = b[:]` produces a new list which is a copy of `b` and replaces the list `a`

The difference is whether we've modified an existing list or created a new one.

To see the difference:

```
a = range(3)
b = range(4)
c = a # c and a now share the same list
a[:] = b
print "a", a
print "b", b
print "C", c
```

All three lists will print out the same. C and a share the same object, so when `a` was modified so was `c`

```
a = range(3)
b = range(4)
c = a # c and a now share the same list
a = b[:]
print "a", a
print "b", b
print "C", c
```

Now c will not print out the same as a. After the assignment, `a` and `c` did not share the same object.

Speedwise, `a[:] = b` is probably a little faster than `a = b[:]`. The first form doesn't have to create a new list object, it can merely modify the existing list. A big part of this is that it can reuse the memory already owned by the list rather then allocating new memory.