# python pass list as function parameter

Tags: python, list, function

folks,

The result of the following code is []
Why is it not ['0','1','2']? If I want to make psswd equal to number in the function foo, what should I do?

```
number = ['0','1','2']
def foo(psswd):
    psswd = number[:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    psswd = []
    foo(psswd)
    print psswd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
number = ['0','1','2']
def foo(psswd):
    psswd = number[:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    psswd = []
    foo(psswd)
    print psswd
```

`psswd = number[:]` rebinds local variable `psswd` with a new list.

I.e., when you do `foo(psswd)`, function `foo` is called, and local variable `passwd` inside it is created which points to the global list under the same name.

When you do `psswd = <something>` inside `foo` function, this `<something>` is created/got and local name `psswd` is made to point to it. Global variable `psswd` still points to the old value.

If you want to change the object itself, not the local name, you must use this object's methods. `psswd[:] = <smething>` actually calls `psswd.__setitem__` method, thus the object which is referenced by local name `psswd` is modified.

Answer (score 12):

You need to mutate instead of rebinding, with [slice-assigning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4081587/20862).

```
psswd[:] = number[:]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
number = ['0','1','2']
def foo(psswd):
    psswd[:] = number  # swap the slice around here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    psswd = []
    foo(psswd)
    print psswd
```