# What does list[:] = process_list(list) does in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between list and list[:] in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081561/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-list-in-python)

I am quite new in python so I bumped into a situation where I was unable to find a response for the following question.

What does this means in python?

```
l[:] = process_list(l)
```

`l` is type `list`

Basically I have a global declared list that I want to modify it(override the old values with the new ones) based on the response of the process_list method. When I try like this:

```
l = process_list(l)
```

I get this: `Unresolved reference 'l'`

Can you please explain what is the difference and if the first approach that I am using currently is a good one?

Comment: Is it really called list? list is a built-in type, you shouldn't call a variable "list"

Comment: @DiegoBasch: no is not called "list", but I wanted to keep it simple and obvious and i forgot that python has this built in type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a function, an assignment to a name that could be a local variable creates a local variable by that name, even if it shadows a global:

```
a = None
def foo():
    a = 5  # local 'a' shadows global 'a'
```

Slice assignment is modification, not assignment, so the name continues to refer to the global:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
def foo():
    a[:] = [5]  # modifies global 'a'
```

The `Unresolved reference` happens because by creating a local variable shadowing the global, the global can no longer be seen.  Another way to do what you want could be to use `global`:

```
a = None
def foo():
    global a
    a = 5  # rebinds global 'a'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear and simple explanation!

Comment: Can you help me with something? I am trying to assign to that list(globally declared) a dictionary. Until a point in the program I used it as a list but now I am want it as a dictionary. What should be the best way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: @andreea.sandu use `global a`, then you can write `a = {}`.

Answer (score 2):

`list[:] = whatever`  will  change the contents of the existing list

(as opposed to replacing it with `list = whatever`) ... by the way `list` is a terrible variable name ...

Comment: you are right about the name, but in my code is not like this. I forgot that python has this built in type.