# Appending to list of lists in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am currently iterating through one value of a list. On each iteration, I append the list to a new list, in order to have a list of lists. However, the outputs that I am receiving aren't what I am expecting them to be.

I've simplified the problem as much as possible and have arrived at this :

```
def Function():
     ListOfLists = []
     Lists = [0]
     for j in range(0, 5):
         Lists[0] = Lists[0] + 1
         print(Lists)
         ListOfLists.append(Lists)
     print("ListofLists:")
     print(ListOfLists)

Function()
```

The output gives me this :

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
ListofLists:
[[5], [5], [5], [5], [5]]
```

I would've expected the output to be :

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
ListofLists:
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Where am I going wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to append a copy of list. When you say `List`, it's a reference. When `List` changes, `ListOfLists` changes. Making a copy prevents this so-called (un)expected behaviour.

Replace this line of code:

```
ListOfLists.append(Lists)
```

with:

```
ListOfLists.append(Lists[:])
```

Comment: For my own understanding, this means that ListOfLists.append(Lists) is storing a reference to Lists?

Edit : hygull answered this comment just below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is because all appended instances are referring to the same address in memory.

#### PROBLEM:

```
In [1]: def Function(): 
   ...:      ListOfLists = [] 
   ...:      Lists = [0] 
   ...:      for j in range(0, 5): 
   ...:          Lists[0] = Lists[0] + 1 
   ...:          print(Lists) 
   ...:          ListOfLists.append(Lists) 
   ...:      print("ListofLists:") 
   ...:      print(ListOfLists) 
   ...:  
   ...: Function()                                                                             
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
ListofLists:
[[5], [5], [5], [5], [5]]
```

---

#### SOLUTION:

Check Check [What is the difference between list and list[:] in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081561/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-list-in-python/4081583).

> Use `[:]` for creating a different object (shallow copy) in this case. You read about **deep copy** and **shallow copy** in Python to understand more about how actually Python treats with references. For more details, check https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/shallow-deep-copy.

Replace `ListOfLists.append(Lists)` with `ListOfLists.append(Lists[:])`.

```
In [2]: def Function(): 
   ...:      ListOfLists = [] 
   ...:      Lists = [0] 
   ...:      for j in range(0, 5): 
   ...:          Lists[0] = Lists[0] + 1 
   ...:          print(Lists) 
   ...:          ListOfLists.append(Lists[:]) 
   ...:      print("ListofLists:") 
   ...:      print(ListOfLists) 
   ...:  
   ...: Function()                                                                             
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
ListofLists:
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]

In [3]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def Function():
    ListOfLists = []
    for j in range(0, 5):
        ListOfLists.append([j+1])
    print(ListOfLists)
Function()
```

Comment: While the output of this code does match the output that I was expecting, it doesn't work in the larger problem / code that I was trying to code. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

When you append `Lists` to `ListofLists`, it does not make a separate copy the list and append it. Instead, it just appends a reference to the `List` list inside `ListofLists`. This is often confusing as a beginner. If you mutate `List` next time, the value inside `ListofLists` will also change as both of them are referencing the same list. If you want to have a completely separate list every time, you should use `copy()` method on list or `Lists[:]'. Or you can create the list on the fly while appending, as follows:

```
ListofLists = []
for number in range(1,6):
    print([number])
    ListofLists.append([number])
print(ListofLists)
```

And much more simple and readable way would be to use a list comprehension, like follows:

```
ListofLists = [[number] for number in range(1, 6)]
print(ListofLists)
```