# Numpy arrays and identity operator is

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing, identity-operator

Having a numpy array like x and a slice that includes all its elements as z, why the identity operators gives false, despite the fact that changing the value of any element in z reflects on x and vice versa

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

z = x[:]

x is z 

# Output:
False
```

Comment: `id(x) != id(z)`  x is an array, z is a slice of that array ...

Comment: Hope It helps. Here's a Link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081561/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-list-in-python>

Comment: @Himanshu no, it's not the same thing at all. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

From [Numpy Internals](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/internals.html):

> NumPy arrays consist of two major components, the raw array data (from now on, referred to as the data buffer), and the information about the raw array data.

in the case of slicing `z = x[:]`, it is a view, NumPy stores the significant set of data that describes how to interpret the data in the data buffer at the different memory location but it can share elements from `z`, hence both have different id and hence `False`.

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> z = x[:] # same as x.view()
>>> x[2]
3
>>> x[2] = 1
>>> x
array([1, 2, 1, 4, 5])
>>> z
array([1, 2, 1, 4, 5])
>>> x is z
False
```

If you modify `x`, `z` will be also modified.
More reference at [Numpy Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#view-or-shallow-copy)

Comment: No, `z` is not a copy of `x`, it's a view of `x`. There is no copying going on.

Comment: by copy, I mean it has the same elements/values as `x`(due to `:`)

Comment: Important note... just kidding

Comment: You're still incorrect. Numpy is different from Python lists. There is only one array - `x`. `z` is a *slice* or a *view* into that array. It's like looking at an object through a window. Creating the same elements in a different memory location is called *copying*.