# What does the [:] do?

Tags: python

```
li = ['random values', True]
li[:] = 'some text'
```

If I print this out, the list becomes
`['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 't', 'e', 'x', 't']`.
*Why does this happen?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between list and list\[:\] in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081561/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-list-in-python)

Comment: Somewhat. Why is each letter split into a different value?

Comment: You're assigning an iterable (the string) to a slice of the list (where the slice is the entire list).  So the elements of the list become the individual characters of the string.